# Proper SSAS terminology related to dimensions, measures?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

Slowly but surely I'm beginning to understand the basic idea of an OLAP cube. Unfortunately, I'm a little confused on the wording used when talking about it.

For example, I have a physical table called `DimPromotion` that looks like this:

[image]

Which translates to this when Excel connects to the cube:
[image]

Let's say I want to add another row to `DimPromotion` called *Touring-5000 Promotion* and the fact table will have orders that fall under the promotion. I will eventually drag&drop this new dimension in Excel. Is it correct to say that I'm adding a new promotion dimension? Or what's the proper terminology for this specific action?

Also, in Excel there's an internet sales count of 13 for *Touring-1000 Promotion* and 58247 orders for *No Discount*. Is this a measure or measure group of a promotion dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your "DimPromotion" is a dimesnsion with "PromotionKey" as DimensionKey "EnglishPromotionName" as a Dimension Hierarchy(dont confuse it with user hierarchy. you will experience them soon if you havent already experienced them). If you add another value or row to your dimension you will be adding a new Hierarchy Member.

Now Lets consider a Fact Table that lists the count of sales and the amount of sales in two diffrent columns. Each of these column is a measure CountOfSales and AmountOfSales. Whereas since they both are from the same tables you say their MeasureGroup is same.

Edit

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why is "Calendar Quarter" an attribute when I open the Date dimension?

Comment: As explained above there are two types of Hierarchies, UserHierarchy and AttributeHierarchy. Now in the image I added you will see some labels with a rectengular image(with 6 smalls squares) This indicates it is an attribute or Hierarchy. Now you will see Date.Calendar with a pyramid arrangement of Squares, and it has further lablels within it with 1,2,3,4,5. This pyramid indicates a user hierarchy and the squares/labels within are levels

Comment: Does the above help?